# jQueryUI Autocomplete id value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor, autocomplete

How to get another field (like Id) in jQueryUI Autocomplete rather then label itself?
(In MVC Razor)

I use the `autocomplete` and it works, but I want a field (or maybe more than one field) in addition to the label.

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Do you want the `id` in the `input` when the user selects a value?

Comment: I have an input. With `autocomplete` I can set a label (like `BookTitle`) for search result, but I can get another field in result like `BookId`.

Answer (score 0):

In your markup:

```
<input type="text" class="item" id="input_autocomplete_1" custom_attr="XXX" />
```

in your js:

```
     $('.item').autocomplete({
                    source: function( request, response ) {
//to send the custom attribute to the populate function
                        customAttr = this.element.attr('custom_attr');
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: {
                                term : request.term,
                                custom_attr: customAttr 
                            },
                            success: function( data ) {
//return a json with label, id and custom
                                response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                                    return {
                                        label: item.label,
                                        id: item.id,
                                        custom: item.custom
                                    }
                                }));
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
//if you want to do something when the item is selected
                       //you can access:
                       //ui.item.id;
                       //ui.item.custom; 
                    }
                });
```